# Can one be »Zum Kuren an den Wolfgangsee«?

Tags: preposition

The below paragraph appears in the article “[Die Lage am Mittwoch](http://www.spiegel.de/politik/deutschland/news-wo-steckt-angela-merkel-a-1220872.html)” in today's online edition of *Der Spiegel*:

> Merkels Öffentlichkeitsarbeiter wiederum möchten nichts zur Aufklärung des Falles beitragen, und so rätselt nun die Republik, wohin die Kanzlerin wohl ohne ihren Ehemann geflüchtet ist: zum Bocciaspiel nach Cadenabbia? **Zum Kuren an den Wolfgangsee?** Oder will sie allen Merkel-muss-weg-Rufern mal demonstrieren, wie es in der Republik aussähe, wenn es nicht mehr MMW hieße, sondern: MIW.

My question refers to the sentence highlighted in bold in the above paragraph. Why *Zum Kuren* and not *Zu den Kuren*? Shouldn't *zu* be followed by *den* before a noun in its plural form? The plural form of *die Kur* is *die Kuren*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are well-formed sentences based on the same principle:

> Peter fährt zum Angeln an den Bodensee.
>
> Maria fährt zum Schwimmen an die Nordsee.
>
> Heinz fährt zum Wandern in die Alpen.
>
> Angela fährt zum Kuren an den Wolfgangsee.

These sentences are completely okay. They use the verb (wandern, angeln, schwimmen, kuren) as a substantive.

This one is also common, but only in rather sloppy oral communication:

> Bruno fliegt zum sich Erholen auf die Malediven.

where the same syntax model is used with a *reflexive* verb. In written communication, this would be perceived as the utterance of a person with lacking education. Even in oral communication it can be perceived as such (unless the low-level speach register is used ironically).

The fully accepted way of saying (and writing) something about Bruno's activity would be

> Um sich zu erholen, fliegt Bruno auf die Malediven.

Less well-recieved are sentences such as

> Markus fliegt zum Huren auf die Philippinen.

although they are grammatically (and probably also fact-wise) correct.

Comment: @johnl  Wenn es "unverschämt" ist, bei Vorliegen bestimmter Charakteristika von mangelnder Bildung zu sprechen, können wir auch alle Schulen schließen, denn die Schulpflicht beruht ja nur darauf, dass man davon ausgeht, dass ein bestimmtes Bildungsniveau um jeden Preis erreicht werden sollte. - Direkt zur Sache: Wenn ausreichende sprachliche Bildung heißt, dass eine Person sich in allen für sie praktisch vorkommenden Situationen angemessen ausdrücken kann (in Wort und Schrift), dann ist jemand, der nicht weiß, wo er "ich war zum mich Erholen" besser nicht schreiben sollte, mangelhaft gebildet.

Answer (score 3):

> Why Zum Kuren and not Zu den Kuren? Shouldn't zu be followed by den before a noun in its plural form? The plural form of die Kur is die Kuren.

*Kuren* is meant as a verb in that case (short for *eine Kur machen*), not plural.

Comment: Es ist „das Kuren“ eine Substanstivierung von „kuren“, was wiederum von „die Kur“ abgeleitet ist.

Comment: In Austria, the passive form "Auf Kur an den Wolfgangsee" would also be quite commonly in use. I personally, have hardly ever heard or read the active form "zum Kuren", maybe its an Austriacism to use the passive form, or it's just coincidence.

Answer (score 2):

> (...) rätselt nun die Republik, wohin die Kanzlerin wohl ohne ihren
>   Ehemann geflüchtet ist: (...) Zum Kuren an den Wolfgangsee?

Wieso *zum Kuren* und nicht *zu den Kuren*?

Weil das erste die Antwort auf die Frage "Wozu" ist, während das zweite die Frage "Zu wem" beantwortet.

Sie will dort eine Kur durchführen, nicht mehrere Kuren aufsuchen, wird spekuliert.

> Shouldn't *zu* be followed by *den* before a noun in its plural form? The plural form of *die Kur* is *die Kuren*. (Hervorhebung von mir; uu)

Wie Carsten S. in einem Kommentar richtig bemerkte, ist „das Kuren“ eine Substantivierung von „kuren“, also das Absolvieren einer Kur.

*Anmerkung am Rande: In den Zeiten unserer Vorfahren gab es einen Kanzler, Helmut Kohl, der im Sommerurlaub immer zum Kuren an den Wolfgangssee fuhr. Vom Bocciaspielen weiß ich nichts, es könnte aber zu seinem Nachfolger Schröder passen.*